# Design: Stateless Prototypes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, prototype, stateless

I got used to create Spring beans for Service, DAO or Controller objects as Singletons. Well, it seems natural to me. Now a colleague of mine likes to make all such objects Prototypes.

What can be the reasons against that? Or pro?

The only thing I can state is the overhead of new instance creation every time the bean is referenced. Though I feel this approach is very wrong and there must be more reasons.

Answer (score 0):

All beans must be in singleton scope, unless there's some very specific reason for them not to be. One such reason is having state. (It is no surprise that the default scope is singleton)

Comment: > beans must be in singleton scope <  


This **is** my question. I feel this is true and would like to transform this feeling into _arguments_.

Comment: the argument is 1. it's the default scope. 2. there is no reason for a prototype - what do you get from it?

Comment: Don't consider me just a wrangler, but these are slightly tautology-like. That is, I would like to see why is singleton the default scope. I came to one more reason against prototypes: 1. Performance (new instance creation + synchronization) 2. Coupling to calls to getBean

Comment: @Leonid - it is just common sense - don't create multiple instance if you don't need them. Do you need them here? No, you don't. The .getBean(..) is not required, you can have prototypes injected (it's handled with a proxy)